# Can't figure out the speed of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel in OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

im using clEnqueueNDRangeKernel function and it's rather faster than clEnqueueTask. Still, I can't make it faster than 16 ms, even adding more global_item_size doesn't help. It just stops working faster on global_item_size = 3 and that's all, still I think that it should work faster with more global_size. Am I wrong? And how can I fix it?

```
__kernel void red_to_green(__global unsigned char *pDataIn, __global unsigned char *pDataOut, unsigned int InSize, unsigned int OutSize)
{


    unsigned int gid = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned int gsize = get_global_size(0);
    unsigned int lid = get_local_id(0);
    unsigned int lsize = get_local_size(0);



    unsigned int vstart = ((InSize/gsize) * gid);
    unsigned int vstop = (vstart + (InSize/gsize));

    for (unsigned int i = vstart; i < vstop; i+=4)
        {

            pDataOut[i/4]  = (pDataIn[i] + pDataIn[i + 1] + pDataIn[i + 2]) / 3;

        }
```

}

```
    vector<unsigned char> pDataIn;
    vector<unsigned char> pDataOut;
    SizeIn = pDataIn.size();
    SizeOut = pDataOut.size();
const size_t cycles_max = 100;
clock_t t4 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i<cycles_max; i++){

    double start_time =  clock();
    double search_time = 0;
    //float last_time = 0;

    //execute opencl kernel
    //ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel, 0, NULL, NULL);

    size_t global_item_size = 3;
    size_t local_item_size = 1;

    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue,kernel, 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    //copy from buffer
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobj1, CL_TRUE, 0, pDataOut.size(), pDataOut.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);

    ret = clFinish(command_queue);

    double end_time = clock(); // конечное время
    search_time = end_time - start_time;
    //float last_time = last_time + search_time;
    cout << search_time << " ms" << endl;

    }
    clock_t t5 = clock();
    double time_seconds2 = (t5-t4)*CLOCKS_PER_SEC/cycles_max;
    cout << "Average time: " << time_seconds2/1000 << " ms" <<endl;
    WriteBmpFile(L"3840x2160_ndrange.bmp", iWidth, iHeight, 8, pDataOut.size(), pDataOut.data(), false);
    system("PAUSE");
```

[Output time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWoVc.png)

Comment: What plaform are you running on? OS type, execution on CPU or GPU, which CPU or GPU?

Comment: A warning to you that `clock()` does not measure wall-clock time; It actually measures (userland) CPU time consumed by the process, and that can be more or less than wall-clock time. A CPU time greater than wall-clock time happens when you have multiple threads all compute-bound; A CPU time less than wall-clock time happens when the process is generally I/O-bound, waiting on the kernel to do something on its behalf. So if you're running the kernel under CPU, `clock()` would count that,  but if you're running under GPU it would not.

Comment: I'm working on Windows 8, Visual Studio 12, execution on GPU, GPU Nvidia GT 740M. Hm, that's interesting, thanks, then how can I count time running on GPU?

Comment: Actually, the implementation of `clock` on Windows is b0rked in the sense that it reports "wall-clock time". But it's not guaranteed to be very accurate, and of course, the time the GPU is busy is not necessarily directly related to how much `clock` moved forward. I would definitely use `chrono::steady_clock` and then `duration_cast` to either milli or nanoseconds.

Comment: I would also avoid measuring the time to read/write the buffer.  For benchmarking purposes, add a `clFinish()` after the enqueueNDRange and take the time there - assuming your file is a 4K image, you're potentially copying a few megabytes across the PCIe bus, which isn't a time of zero - in fact, it may be the majority of the time.

Comment: You can use https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetEventProfilingInfo.html to measure the time in the GPU (assuming the code runs on the GPU...)

Comment: Thanks! But still maybe someone got an idea how to fix that code? Pleeeeease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Still, I can't make it faster than 16 ms, even adding more
>   global_item_size doesn't help. It just stops working faster on
>   global_item_size = 3 and that's all, still I think that it should work
>   faster with more global_size. Am I wrong? And how can I fix it?

Increasing global size only won't help as you set local size to 1. This means your work group size is 1 which is very inefficient. GPU Nvidia GT 740M has got 2 computing units which means in general that it can run 2 work groups simultaneously hence you see no improvement after your global size is set to 3.

Try increasing local size to at least 128 to fully utilize the GPU (or 512 or 1024). [CUDA Occupancy Calculator](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) can be helpful in figuring out optimal settings.